# VBA Auto filter with not exact match (based on cell value)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make auto filter using VBA by specific number in specific cell, but the issue here is that the result be exacted with the same number only, while I need any result contains this number even if it was less than or more than this number.

I tried this code

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AD").AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:=Range("$I$1")
```

sample of my filter value: `1119445113`

sample of my filter result:

any not exact match like: `1119445113`, `2201119445113`, `11194451133` or `ST1119445113`... etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use stars to denote partial (or no) match from left and right:

```vb
Criteria1:="*" & Range("$I$1") & "*"
```

Comment: it doesn't give me any things in the filter, nether the exacted values nor partial values
and you can try it.
 Sub filter()

Range("A:G").AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="*" & Range("$I$1") & "*"

End Sub